# How to enable standard keyboard shortcuts for the service console?

Tags: servicecloud, service-cloud-console, console

How to enable keyboard shortcuts for the salesforce console? do we need to write any coding to enable standard keyboard shortcuts? Enable shortcut keys option is disabled in my dev org?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

check below link  for enable keyboard shortcuts in your organization

https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewHelpDoc?id=console2_setup_keyboard_shortcuts.htm&language=en

Comment: If sathya has answered your question, @baskaran, please vote it up and mark it as the answer.

Comment: @MikeChale Sure.